# catkin make and running hrl_tilting_hokuyo

Tags: python, catkin-make, catkin, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running hydro and switching over from new rosbuild to using catkin. I read through the catkin conceptual overview and tutorials but have trouble implementing.

I'm trying to get the tilting hokuyo set up. I 'catkinized' the hrl_hardware_drivers but having trouble with the hrl_lib. It wasn't included in the package so I found it externally. When I run:

rosrun hrl_hokuyo hokuyo_processing.py

It goes me the error:

src/hrl_hokuyo/hokuyo_processing.py", line 43, in 
import hrl_lib.transforms as tr
ImportError: No module named hrl_lib.transforms

I believe the cmakelist and package.xml file was edit appropriately to include hrl_lib. I want to do it right and not just add the hrl_lib folder into the directory.

Thanks!

Heres is the cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(hrl_hokuyo)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS hokuyo_node sensor_msgs rospy hrl_lib)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

catkin_package(
    DEPENDS hokuyo_node sensor_msgs rospy hrl_lib
    CATKIN_DEPENDS # TODO
    INCLUDE_DIRS # TODO
    LIBRARIES # TODO
)
```

Here is the package.xml

```
<package>
  <name>hrl_hokuyo</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <description>Python class that uses hokuyo_node from ros-pkg to get scans from
  UTMs and player to get scans from URGs.</description>
  <maintainer email=""></maintainer>

  <license>New BSD</license>

  <url type="website"></url>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>hokuyo_node</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>hrl_lib</build_depend>

  <run_depend>hokuyo_node</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>hrl_lib</run_depend>

</package>
```

Edit #1

I'm still having trouble with it. Is the hrl_lib package just a folder with the python files in it? This doesn't feel right since there are other folders with the library as well. Here is my structure:

```
/path_to_workspace/
    /src
        /hrl_hokuyo
            /setup.py
            /src
                /hrl_hokuyo
                /hrl_lib
```

Thanks for the quick response and breaking it down for me.

Edit#2

I didn't edit it much except just setting the path.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['hrl_lib'],
    package_dir={'/path_to_directory_containing_hrl_lib/': 'src'}
)

setup(**d)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93186/catkin-make-and-running-hrl_tilting_hokuyo/) by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2013-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on 2013-10-22**:
Thanks for the comment and telling me the preferred method to posting responses!

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-10-22**:
Can you post your setup.py? It is likely that you are not declaring your packages correctly.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-10-22**:
Another option is for you to push this to github (or something similar) and point me to it.

**Comment by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on 2013-10-22**:
I'll work on putting this onto github

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-10-22**:
I think you have the `package_dir` wrong, see my edit to my question and this: http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to export python libraries you need to do two things:

- Setup a `setup.py` file describing which Python packages your package has
- Call the `catkin_python_setup()` macro in your `CMakeLists.txt`

Reference: http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html

The `setup.py` should be in the root of your package and look like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['mypkg'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)

setup(**d)
```

Where...

```
    packages=['mypkg'],
```

'mypkg' is the name of the python package you want, in your case probably 'hrl_lib', and...

```
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
```

'src' is the folder in your package where you keep these packages, so your folder structure would be:

```
/path/to/my/package
                   /setup.py
                   /src
                       /hrl_lib
                               /__init__.py
                               ...
```

And in your `CMakeLists.txt` you need to call before `catkin_package(...)`:

```
catkin_python_setup()
```

Also, get rid of these lines:

```
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

This was someting that rosbuild had you do, but you shouldn't do this in catkin.

**EDIT:**

I would expect your `setup.py` to look like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['hrl_hokuyo', 'hrl_lib'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)

setup(**d)
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on 2013-10-23**:
Without the package path at package_dir it works. Thank you!